# How to start just the panel to show list of open windows?

Tags: panel

I am on Ubuntu 10.2 (Amazon Cloud Box). When I minimize a window, it disappears and starts running in the background. When I click the mouse's middle button it comes back to the foreground. Is there a way I can have start something like  just panel (may be xPanel) which will show me all the opened windows and I just have to click on it to bring the application  to fore ground?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got it done as follows 
Remember this is a cloud box and I am looking for a programmatic way of starting just the panel. I have decided on the xfce panel as it is light weight and very easy to customize.

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4-panel
```

make sure you have "task-list" in the panel.

Configuring xfce panel is very simple. To set the default settings for every user one just needs to edit /xdg/xfce4/panel/panel.xml. Its a simple self explanatory xml file.

Answer (score 0):

**Ubuntu Windows List Indicator**

[Window list](https://launchpad.net/~jwigley/+archive/window-list) is an application indicator to display a list of all the current open windows. Each window can be activated by selecting the entry form the list.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jwigley/window-list

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install window-list
```

source: http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu-ppa-repositories/16931-ubuntu-windows-list-indicator

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add a ppa, you could go to the software center and check out Avant Window Navigator or another "dock" that shows minimized windows.